# Django beginner problem: manage.py dbsync

Tags: django

I'm running ubuntu 9.04 32b and got django from Synaptics.
My settings.py is configured for a sqlite3 database.

I've been through this [tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01) and got the following error when trying to run the command `python manage.py syncdb` :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in 
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 340, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 295, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 192, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 51, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 56, in cursor
    cursor = self._cursor(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 145, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Do anyone have a clue on my problem ?

Answer (score 21):

In settings.py are you using a relative path to the sqlite file?

If you are, try changing that to an absolute path.

i.e. instead of:

```
~/project/mydata.db
```

use

```
/home/user/project/mydata.db
```

Comment: This is almost always the problem.  Python doesn't do path expansion when it reads these.

Answer (score 17):

This can also happen if your database name is the same as your project name. To fix it just change the name of your db e.g. by adding a .db to the NAME. So if your DATABASE NAME in settings.py was 'epic_project' change it to 'epic_project.db'

---

**Long and boring explanation**:

If you start your project by running:

```
django startproject epic_project
```

your folder structure will be like this:

- /path/to/epic_project/

  - manage.py
  - epic_project/

    - settings.py

if then in your settings.py you set your database as:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'epic_project',
        ...
    }
}
```

when

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

runs it tries to open or create a sqlite db file at /path/to/epic_project/epic_project, but there is a directory there, so it says "oh ok the path exists already, let's open it as an sqlite db", unfortunately for sqlite it's a directory and not a DB, so it cries and django presents these tears to you as "sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file"

Comment: plus 1 for the humour

Answer (score 9):

might be a permission problem, does your user have sufficient right to write on the folder? for example if you do

```
sudo python manage.py syncdb
```

instead, does it work?

Answer (score 5):

For Google's sake:

The path to the database must be the full path to the file --- not just the directory where the file lives.

Comment: Isn't this what JosefAssad suggested in [their answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/1084782/5420829)?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Windows then realized that syncdb would not create the specified folder if it didn't already exist.  I had specified `c:/mysite/db/sqlite3.db` in settings but the `/db/` folder didn't exist.  Created it in terminal then re-ran syncdb successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem two days ago. I solved it by setting the 'NAME' in the DATABASE dictionary (settings.py) to the absolute path. 
For example.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME' : DATABASE_PATH,
    }
}
```

here you can set the DATABASE_PATH at the top of the settings.py as such
(Not sure if this will work for windows)

```
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir))
DATABASE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'your-database-name'))
```

For Windows you might have to use the replace method. (Not sure .. But you can try it out as follows)

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir).replace('\\', '/'))
```

Same goes for the DATABASE_PATH.
PS. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to answer from user104264 - different perspective...

Currently following the [YouTube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5VlpgEVVg4) I had the same error. Seems to me while running the manage.py in a virtualenv django project directory ...path to virtual env.../django_project/, the database name inside /myapp/settings.py was simply 'storage.db' so

(django-v)...path to virtual env project.../django_project/>python manage.py syncdb

created ...path to virtual env project.../django_project/storage.db

-Bill

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying a full path to db file and are still having issues, try putting an r before the string.

ie.

```
r'C:\home\usr\mysite\sqlite3.db'
```

Comment: That signifies a regular expression, but the problem you're solving is the fact Python doesn't like the single backslashes. You'd be better off with `'C:\\home\\usr\\mysite\\sqlite3.db'`

Comment: @Tom it does not signify a regular expression. It tells python to treat it as a *raw string literal*: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/2259303

Comment: Duh, my bad. 99% of the time I use it is for Django urls so I've got it stuck in my head that way. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was running into was a bootstrapping issue where some model lookups were being done at import (outside of any class or function). [Per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database), this is a bad idea.