# OperationalError:no such table:article_article

Tags: python, django

learning django recently and ran into a problem with Django.
This is my **models.py**:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#/usr/bin/env python
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_time']
```

first I input these in cmd:

1. python manage.py migrate
2. python manage.py makemigrations
3. python manage.py migrate

but when, in the Django shell, I input this code:

```
from article.models import Article
Article.objects.create(title = 'Hello World', category = 'Python', content = 'what')
```

I received this error message:

> **OperationalErrors:no such table:article_ article**

what's wrong?
thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure your migrations ran successfully? What message did you get after steps 2 and 3?

Comment: oh,thank you!i find the mistake

Comment: @evbo: It would be helpful if you communicate how you have solved your problem

Comment: just the app-name,i mistaked them...

Comment: Well! So it would be nice that you marks what answer is useful for you

Comment: well,thank you all the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAYBE something on migrations is not correct...

To create an app:

1) `python manage.py migrate`

2) `python manage.py startapp myapp`

3) add `'myapp',` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in *settings.py*

4) create your model and save

5) `python manage.py makemigrations myapp`

6) `python manage.py migrate myapp`

You have to do the last two steps every time you change something in models.py.

Now some links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262771/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-operationalerror-no-such-table)  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771755/django-operationalerror-no-such-table) and a very useful tutorial [Django Girls](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_models/README.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply erase you db by deleting your db.sqlite
then `./manage.py syncdb`.

If you don't want  to loose your data then you need first, after making syncdb, run `./manage.py makemigrations`, `./manage.py migrate`. 
Than, after changing your models you run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` -these command will make necessary changes to DB schema.