# sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user

Tags: python, flask, web

I am trying to create a simple website with Flask, and keep getting this error message sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user
Tthe d.b is imported for every file, so I don't know where is the problem.
this is the unfinished code. If any one can see what I need to fix please let me know.

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from os import path


db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Loony Toons'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}' 
    db.init_app(app)

    
    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User, Note
        
    create_database(app)

     
    return app


def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
       db.create_all(app=app)
       print('Created Database!')
```

models.py

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')

class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

auth.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from .models import User
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from . import db


auth = Blueprint('auth' ,__name__)

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    return render_template("login.html", boolean=True)

@auth.route('/logout')
def logout():
    return "<p>Logout</p>"

@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET','POST'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       email = request.form.get('email')
       first_name = request.form.get('firstName')
       password1 = request.form.get('password1')
       password2 = request.form.get('password2')

       

       if len(email) < 4:
           flash('Email must be greater then 3 charecters', category='error')
           pass
       elif len(first_name)<2:
           flash('First name must be greater then 1 charecters', category='error')
           pass
       elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords dont match', category='error')
            pass
       elif len(password1) < 7:
            flash('Password must be at least 7 characters', category='error')
            pass
       else:
           new_user = User(email=email, first_name=first_name, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256'))
           db.session.add(new_user)
           db.session.commit()
           flash('Account created!', category='success')
           return redirect(url_for('views.home'))




    return render_template("sign_up.html")
```

Comment: Do any of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28126140/15368978) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14262771/15368978) solve your problem?

Comment: yes it did. i hade to deleat __pycache__ and the db and it worked
thank you